# Does a charged particle experience force in presence of light

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

Light is considered as combination of electric and magnetic fields. So does a charged particle experience electric force in the presence of light?

Comment: see radiation pressure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure  an electron would feel a proportionate effect.

Comment: See my answer to [Have we directly observed the electric component to EM waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327076) for explicit experimental measurements of the force exerted by an optical field on an electron.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but since the electric field in an optical wave oscillate at extremely high frequencies (hundreds of THz), the inertia of the particle prevents it from following this motion. The field switches directions, before the particle can move appreciably in the direction of the field.

The magnetic field does not exert a force on a charged particle, only when it is moving.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laser Cooling is an example of technology where atoms have there motion slowed down by laser light ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling)).

It is a little bit out of scope, because atoms are more electric dipoles than charged particles, but I think it is worth mentioning it.